# Letters In Username or Password Dialog Query from User Trigger the Dialog Buttons

Tags: dialog, robotframework, rpa

I'm writing a robot script in PyCharm to ask a user for a user name & password to then use later to login to software on the web to perform actions.  If you try & use the letters O or C in the user name or password query dialog boxes, it will trigger the OK or Cancel buttons below & continue as if OK was clicked.

This is the code I am using & any help is appreciated:

*** Settings ***

Documentation    A script that enables SSH on a router in software specified by serial number from the user.

Suite Setup  Setup chromedriver

Library  SeleniumLibrary

Library  OperatingSystem

Library  Dialogs

*** Keywords ***

Setup chromedriver
Set Environment Variable  webdriver.chrome.driver  ${EXECDIR}/Users/glen/PycharmProjects/Automation/chromedriver

*** Variables ***

${url}  https://softwarewebsite.com

#${userName}  USERNAME

#${passWord}  PASSWORD

${serial}  ############

${deviceusernum}  Device.Users.User.7.X_OUI_RemoteAccess.1.X_OUI_LANRestriction

${key1}  ACCESS_ENABLE

${deviceuserpass}  Device.Users.User.7.Password

${key2}  accesskey1

${deviceport}  Device.Users.User.7.X_OUI_RemoteAccess.1.Port

${key3}  22

*** Test Cases ***

Get Credentials

```
${CO_username}=   Get Value From User   Enter account user name     admin
Log To Console  \n${ECO_username}
${CO_password}=   Get Value From User   Enter account password   password
Log To Console  \n${ECO_password}
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue with Robot 6.1, I wasn't able to reproduce the issue with robotframework 6.0.1. Can you try to downgrade your robotframework?

Comment: And just to add this has already seemingly been fixed for 6.1.1 but it has not yet been released. See [Github issue](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/4812).

Comment: I downgraded to Robot Framework 6.0.1 & it now works.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded to Robot Framework 6.0.1 as Morkkis suggested & it now works. Thank you!